# Using CoreData to store JSON string

Tags: ios, json, core-data

I have a set of JSON strings where each JSON string will have a key. Now, I want to store these JSON strings on device so that I can use this data later.
Here I do not store any objects on device.
Can I use CoreData or is there any alternative to this?
What is the best practice to store JSON on device?

Comment: If the data really don't have relationship with other objects, you can try using plist. Can you show your JSON?

Comment: My JSON would be like this, {"status":"success","userid":"129","description":"some description"} in this way there will be many JSON strings need to be stored on device.

Comment: If you are going to create a relationship with user and this information it's good to use CoreData or Sqlite. Else you can store json file as such. I would recommend to store in plist, because its easier to form a dictionary or array, edit them and then save it again compared to json, which needs a little more effort to save them. Is there any other information that you need to store.

Comment: Thanks for response, if I want to store 100 or more such JSON strings on plist, will that be able to store such a big data?

Comment: Why do you want to store the data as JSON? Why not parse the data once and store the parsed data instead? It'll use less storage space that way, and it'll be easier to use at the same time. For example, with parsed data you could easily search for records where `userid==129`, but if the data is all JSON you'd have to parse all those strings first in order to do that kind of search.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply save your JSON to a file and deserialize it again when you need it next.

Answer (score 0):

JSON just define the compact data format for fast transfer between server and client (your App).

What's you need to do is decode the JSON data from server to data type NSDictionary, NSArray, NSString... and then if you want to store them use plist, sqlite or CoreData to store.

For CoreData, you need to create Entity associate with JSON format.

Ex: "key":"value" -> NSDictionary

Comment: As I store only set of JSON strings, among CoreData, sqlite, file and plist, which would be preferable to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have much data to store you can use plist or json. Plist would be more easier, if you store json as such you need a couple of more lines of code.

Create a DataHelper class with methods to save,add , findAll, findFirtWithValue:forObject: in it.

Here is a sample

```
#define kPlistFilePath @"Data.plist"
#define kJsonFilePath @"Data.json"

@implementation DataController

+ (NSString *)savedFilePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = paths[0]; 
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kPlistFilePath];
    return filePath;
}

+ (NSArray *)findAll
{   
    NSString *filePath = [self savedFilePath];
    return [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
}

+ (void)saveJSON:(id)object 
{
    NSString *filePath = [self savedFilePath];

    NSArray *unsavedArray = nil;

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        unsavedArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[object dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                       options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                         error:&error];

    }else if([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
        unsavedArray = object;

    }else if([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
        unsavedArray = @[object];
    }

    if ([unsavedArray count]) {
        [unsavedArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
    }
}



+ (NSDictionary *)userInfoForID:(NSString *)userID
{
    NSArray *allData = [self findAll];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userid = %@",userID];
    return [[allData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]lastObject];
}
```